# Android: Crop Image option

Tags: android, crop

I'm working on a project where I need to crop image to set profile picture,
I prefer this [link](http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/07/how-to-crop-image-from-camera-and.html) for that which worked perfect for me when I tested it on `Emulator` but the problem is that when I run my application on My Tab I'm having problem..
It gives me dialog having title `Choose Crop App`but no option means there no app to select to crop the image..

Comment: A search on `android crop image library` on a major search engine turns up lots of possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

```
    final CropImageView cropImageView = (CropImageView) findViewById(R.id.CropImageView);
    cropImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.bike01);
    cropImageView.setAspectRatio(DEFAULT_ASPECT_RATIO_VALUES, DEFAULT_ASPECT_RATIO_VALUES);
    crop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              croppedImage = cropImageView.getCroppedImage();
                ImageView croppedImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.croppedImageView);
                croppedImageView.setImageBitmap(croppedImage);

        }
    });
```

And use this one library to run this code [lib](https://github.com/edmodo/cropper)!